# Ubuntu Java Scene Builder too small on a 4k screen

Tags: javafx

As you can see below the scene builder GUI is far too small

[Scene builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObrEb.png)

How can I change this? My monitor is 4k

Comment: Is there any answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.10 I solved this by adding `java-options=-Dglass.gtk.uiScale=1.5` in `/opt/scenebuilder/lib/SceneBuilder.cfg`

Comment: Where do you find system properties like these that you can modify with `-D<name>=<value>` command line options? I thought System.getProperties() enumerates all possible java options with their current value, but it seems to only output options with non-null values.